# Get only 1st duplicate record oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct

I have tables and i use "inner join" on these tables. i want to get unique data but some values are duplicated. This is my result table. but i can't get uniqe names because of dates are different. i used distinct, group by but no chance.

```
    HSB.Name    HMB.Date
    --------    -------------------
    Michael     15.04.2013 07:55:08
    Madonna     15.04.2013 10:58:17
    Madonna     15.04.2013 11:05:46
    Terry       15.04.2013 11:13:39
    Britney     15.04.2013 11:52:00
    Slash       15.04.2013 11:55:39
    Slash       15.04.2013 11:56:10
```

and my sql is ->

```
     select HSB.Name, HMB.Date 
     from HSB hsb        
     inner join HMB hmb
     on hsb.hsb_no = hmb.hmb_no
     And hsb.hsb_g_no = hmb.hmb_g_no
     where hsb.hsb_kod = '&kod'
     and hsb.hsb_date >= '&date1'
     and hsb.hsb_date < '&date2'
```

Comment: With unique names, which dates you want to associate. You want name and date. So, which row you want to pick in the case of duplicate names. Like say, if the names are duplicate pick the row which has recent HMB.Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select Name,
    Date
FROM(
    select 
        HSB.Name, 
        HMB.Date,
        row_number() over (partition by HSB.Name order by HMB.Date) RNum
     from HSB hsb inner join HMB hmb on hsb.hsb_no = hmb.hmb_no
        And hsb.hsb_g_no = hmb.hmb_g_no
     where 
        hsb.hsb_kod = '&kod' and 
        hsb.hsb_date >= '&date1' and 
        hsb.hsb_date < '&date2'
)x WHERE RNum=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanty to get the date which is recent associated to one Name then try below query.

```
 select HSB.Name, max(HMB.Date) as Date
 from HSB hsb        
 inner join HMB hmb
 on hsb.hsb_no = hmb.hmb_no
 And hsb.hsb_g_no = hmb.hmb_g_no
 where hsb.hsb_kod = '&kod'
 and hsb.hsb_date >= '&date1'
 and hsb.hsb_date < '&date2'
 group by HSB.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

select HSB.Name, max(HMB.Date) 
     from HSB hsb
     inner join HMB hmb
     on hsb.hsb_no = hmb.hmb_no
     And hsb.hsb_g_no = hmb.hmb_g_no
     where hsb.hsb_kod = '&kod'
     and hsb.hsb_date >= '&date1'
     and hsb.hsb_date < '&date2' group by name